# How to find all set intervals using CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

The first handler listens some channel of messages and if there is an incoming message, it sets interval:

`toggleFlagInterval = setInterval (-> toggleFlag), 500`

Messages can be arbitrarily much, but I need to set only one interval.

Second handler reads the message and in it I want to remove the interval:

`clearInterval toggleFlagInterval`

I want to control that was always zero or one interval .
To do this, I need to find all set intervals.

How to find all set intervals using CoffeeScript?

I would be very grateful for your help.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't make sense. You cannot find all functions registered with `setInterval`, with or without CoffeeScript (that would be a JavaScript question, it has nothing to do with CoffeeScript). You just need to keep track of them yourself.

It seems like in this specific case, you simply need to choose to conditionally *not* set an interval, if one is already set.

To do so, your setting code would use `?=`:

```
toggleFlagInterval ?= setInterval (-> toggleFlag), 500
```

And your clearing code would reset `toggleFlagInterval` to `null`:

```
clearInterval toggleFlagInterval
toggleFlagInterval = null
```

Alternatively, you need to cancel any already set interval at the point when you set a new one:

```
clearInterval(toggleFlagInterval) if toggleFlagInterval?
toggleFlagInterval = setInterval (-> toggleFlag), 500
```